# Template-Toolkit and complex variables

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

Say I'm working in Perl using [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). I assign an array of hashes to a a variable, ie:

```
my @array = ($some_hash); 
$c->stash->{foo}->{bar} = \@array;
```

How do I select an element from $some_hash, such as 'id', in [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/)? In Perl I can access it via `$c->stash->{foo}->{bar}->[0]->id`...

All help is greatly appreciated, and I'm a bit of a Perl newb, so if anything looks out of place, please let me know. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12):

[Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) uses a unified syntax for accessing elements of complex structures. This should do what you want:

```
[% foo.bar.0.id %]
```

Answer (score 6):

The following kind of thing is helpful when you want to work out what's going on in complex data structures in [TT](http://template-toolkit.org/):

```
[% USE Dumper; Dumper.dump_html(foo) %]
```

.. see what kind of data [TT](http://template-toolkit.org/) thinks you have:

```
[% foo %]
```

... or further down the rabbit warren:

```
[% FOREACH x IN foo.keys; 
USE Dumper; Dumper.dump_html(foo.$x);
foo.$x ; # to see what kind of ref it is
END %]
```

Comment: Using the last example displays: "$VAR1 = 1; 1" Which is not quite what I'm looking for. Using the next to last one shows that it's a hash. Using the first example displays nothing.

Comment: yep, sorry.  Fiddling with complex data structures is a bit of a pain in TT.    but the idea is to use the Dumper plugin to work out what it is you have, and act appropriately.

Comment: The fact that foo.$x is returning 1 (or true, depending on how you look at it), suggests to me that it might be a clash of VMethod name and hash key problem - see my second answer...

Comment: THANKS! - This worked fantastic for me, old one, but really saved me TONS of time as I was trying to build up a hash and was having "issues".

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate you've used the famous *foo* and *bar* methods/keys in your example.

One gotcha in TT is a clash of VMethod name and hash-key. Is it possible that your key name conflicts with one of the built-in TT VMethods? `.first`, `.last`, `.length` or even `.keys` are candidates for this, and [there are probably others](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html).

This can lead to unexpected results, particular when you throw in [Automagic Promotion of Scalar to List for Virtual Methods](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_Automagic_Promotion_of_Scalar_to_List_for_Virtual_Methods) behaviour.

The solution to this is to use the `item()` VMethod, ie:

```
[% foo.item("bar").0.id %]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$some_hash` appears to be blessed from the way you access it in perl, I'd try something like

```
[% foo.bar.0.id() %]
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have set a local TT variable called `foo` somewhere in your existing code? You can get some mysterious results if that happens, along the lines of "I agree that this should work; but it doesn't".

One way to check this is to make your `foo` explicit, ie:

```
[% c.stash.foo.bar.0.id %]
```

If that produces a result, then you've got a namespace problem somewhere.